# Axios frontend doesn't seem to pass request parameters to backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, axios

I have this hook on react for my frontend to perform http requests to get data to show on page

```
useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/postersgrid`,
      params: { query: props.query },
    };

    axios
      .request(options)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setResults(res.data.results);
        setTotalPages(res.data.total_pages);
        setSuccessfulRequest(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setSuccessfulRequest(false);
      });
  }, [props.query]);
```

as you can see that endpoint is mine because i made a little backend for my app

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const axios = require("axios");

const PORT = 8080;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

app.get("/api/v1/postersgrid", (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&query=${req.query}`,
  };

  axios
    .request(options)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

this backend communicates with an api of which i have the api key.
What i want is:

1. frontend queries backend where api key is hidden
2. backend queries api and returns data to frontend

Now the problem is when i try to pass parameters from frontend to backend

```
const options = {
      method: "GET",
      url: `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/postersgrid`,
      params: { query: props.query },
    };
```

here i try to pass it to backend but as soon as i use it in the url to perform http requests to the api it's like it's undefined or null

```
url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&query=${req.query}`,
```

to prove this works, if i change the query to be static

```
url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&query=war`
```

everything works as intended, where am I wrong? btw I'm doing all of this instead of performing requests directly from frontend to hide my api key correctly

Comment: `...&query=${req.query.query}`

Answer (score 0):

Had to change this

```
url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&query=${req.query}
```

to this

```
url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${APIKEY}&query=${req.query.query}
```